# Why is my Erbauer 230mm 110v Angle Grinder smoking from the upper body area?

Tags: powertools, angle-grinder, smoke

When I turn my Erbauer 230mm 110v Angle Grinder on, the motor powers up, the gears turn and it all seems to work fine. After about 10-15 seconds it starts to smoke, but with no strange noise, and not any smell of burning. Does anyone know what could be causing this?

I've checked the brushes and they're fine, and there doesn't appear to be any incorrect wiring, or any foreign matter inside it.
Much appreciated.

Comment: Are your brushes "fine" in the sense that they're not worn past the minimum service indicators?

Comment: If you've had it apart to check the brushes, some clear, focused pics of the interior may help someone identify an issue. [Edit] them into your post (click the "sun & mountain" icon above the text box and they'll be uploaded & hosted for you).

Comment: excess lubricant on the rotor can smoke in the brushes till its "burned off". does the smoke smell like burning wd40 or more acrid like burning insulation (If the windings are shorted, a portion of the wire could be getting very hot, and will burn the insulation till it shorts further and eventually either pops the breaker, or melts something.

Comment: probably a short in the winding in the rotor or stater.  Sorry,  but it's probably toast.

Comment: Thanks for your replies everyone. I'll investigate later today and see what's going on inside with your suggestions in mind.

Comment: @isherwood Yeah the brushes are pretty much new. Regards

Comment: Although I agree with George it very well may be a shorted winding, it could be moisture, I run heaters on staters (the motor windings) to dry them out  I keep the temp 120-150 and bake them out sometimes for days (for big motors) but a small motor like that over night at 120f should be enough to dry it out, it’s worth a try because letting the magic smoke out ruins the motor. Just a little it may be ok when dried out.